# Data not getting saved after copying data from one sheet to another using java

Tags: java, excel

I am using below code to copy couple of columns from one sheet to another in excel. But data is getting copied to new sheet but when i open that file and try to close it, it asks do you want to save it? What should i do.

```
 FileInputStream fis;
    try {

        fis = new FileInputStream("C:\\Banks\\SBI.xlsx");
        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
        XSSFSheet Sheet1 = wb.getSheet("new sheet");
        XSSFSheet nfrntSheet = wb.createSheet("Original");

    int n = Sheet1.getLastRowNum();
    System.out.println(n);
    for(int i = 0;i<n+11;i++)
    {
        XSSFRow r = nfrntSheet.createRow(i);
        Cell c = r.createCell(0);
        c.setCellFormula("'new sheet'!A"+(i-9));
        nfrntSheet.autoSizeColumn(0);
    }
    for(int i = 0;i<n+11;i++)
    {
        XSSFRow r = nfrntSheet.getRow(i);
        Cell c = r.createCell(1);
        c.setCellFormula("'new sheet'!C"+(i-9));
        nfrntSheet.autoSizeColumn(1);
    }
    for(int i = 0;i<=7;i++)
    {
        nfrntSheet.setColumnWidth(i, 5000);
    }

   nfrntSheet.setColumnWidth(1, 12000);
   nfrntSheet.setColumnWidth(17, 30000);
    fis.close();
    FileOutputStream stream= new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\Banks\\SBI.xlsx"));
    wb.write(stream);
    stream.close();    
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(CommandLineApp.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(CommandLineApp.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Comment: I think it is not a Problem with your code. It is a Problem with excel

Comment: what should i do for it?

Comment: i think you can not do anything

Comment: If i mail that file without manually saving, it wont be updated

Comment: ok thanks you jens

Comment: But do a wb.Close() after writing

Comment: Jens still its not working